# Looking for a book about a boy who becomes a healer

Tags: story-identification, books

It's a young adult book about a young boy who wants to go to school to be a healer and he does and is very good at it and for that he is targeted by very powerful people for his gift of healing that's about all I remember and I think his brother dies

Comment: I highly recommend going to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and seeing if you can answer any of the questions there. For example, when did you read this? Do you remember anything about the cover? What language was it in? How long was it?

Comment: You might also want to wander over to [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and work your way through the checklists there.

Comment: What was the setting? What age/ethnicity was the boy? What was the boy's name? Were there any other characters in the book? Did he want to be a *magical* healer or just a normal doctor? Why were his healing skills special? Who were the "powerful people" targeting him? Why couldn't they just hire him? What did his brother die from?

Comment: What aspect of this is Sci-Fi or Fantasy? (Do we assume "healer" refers to magical healer?)

Comment: I think it could have definitely been a better question, but it sufficed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blind guess from keywords, *[Secret Sacrament](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/118769.Secret_Sacrament)*. It's a young adult book with a young boy who becomes a healer. According to the reviews, his brother dies in the course of the book.

[image: Book cover]

> Terrified, a young Navaron child watches helplessly from his hiding place as a young Shinili woman is brutally beaten and abused by a group of drunken Navaron men. Too frightened to answer her pleas for help, the child runs away, taking with him the sacred bone carving of the Shinili people. In doing so, he forever binds himself and his fate to them. Gabriel is no ordinary boy. His life is now marked out for greatness by powers beyond his understanding...He's never wanted to follow in his father's footsteps and become a wealthy, sea-faring merchant, celebrated by all in the ancient empire of Navora - but cold and distant to his family. Haunted by a terrible childhood secret Gabriel spurns family tradition and duties as the eldest son, to pursue a life of helping others. Derived from a deep sense of guilt and strange mysterious visions Gabriel knows that he is destined to become a healer, with the power to decipher dreams, no matter what his overbearing family argues. But against his will, Gabriel finds himself caught up in the power struggles of a corrupt Empire, endangering all that he loves. His decision to hold true to his destiny is one that will cost him dearly, and one that threatens to tear apart the entire Navoran Empire - but which might just end up saving an entire people.

Comment: +1 from me. It's the same one I found when I googled for ***"young adult fantasy" + "a healer" + "dead brother"***

Comment: That is the book thank you so much have been looking for this book for a long time

Comment: @Nick - Such a shame you didn't think to use google.

Comment: Eh, sometimes it's a matter of using the right keywords, and recognizing the chaff from the wheat. This was the 4th or 5th book in the list I came up with in my tabs.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - If you google the question title, this book is fifth on the list

Comment: @Valorum: *wry grin* Google being what it is, I don't get the same results. It's not even on the page for me.

Comment: @Valorum Instead of using evil Google, he used neutral Stack Exchange, and he got a good answer. Why is that "a shame"?

Comment: @user14111 - Because it suggests a [lack of research effort](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2VsiV.png) on the part of the OP, something which is likely to result in downvoting

Comment: @Valorum So typing in a Google search form is "research effort" but typing in a Stack Exchange question form is not. Of course that makes no sense, but I'm sure you have an amusing rationalization.

Comment: @user14111 - It makes perfect sense, you're just being **intentionally** argumentative :-) In this instance it would appear that the OP has done precisely nothing to find the book themselves or else they'd have found it with consummate ease.

Comment: @Valorum: I disagree with your assertion, but I'll admit that they weren't far from finding their own answer.